# str_extract() and summarise() gives me na row

Tags: r, grouping, summary, summarize

This should be pretty straightforward, as think I'm just looking for verification about what I'm seeing.

I'm trying to use `str_extract()` to pull areas of interest out of a column in my data frame, and then count how often each word appears.  I'm running into an issue though where when I do this, the data frame I produce has `NA` listed in one of the rows.  This is confusing to me, because I don't know what is causing it or if it is a sign of an error in my code.  I'm not sure how to fix this.

Additionally, note that the last item in words is "the table is light", which contains two of the words of interest in this example.  I've done this intentionally because I want to make sure that it will be counted twice.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(words =c("paper book", "food press", "computer monitor", "my fancy speakers",
                 "my two dogs", "the old couch", "the new couch", "loud speakers", 
                 "wasted paper", "put the dishes away", "set the table", "put it on the table", 
                 "lets go to church", "turn out the lights", "why are the lights on",
                 "the table is light"))

keep <- c("dogs|paper|table|light|couch")

new_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Subject = str_extract(words, keep), n = n()) %>% 
  group_by(Subject)%>%
  summarise(`Word Count` = length(Subject))
```

This is what I'm getting now

```
 Subject `Word Count`
  <chr>          <int>
1 couch              2
2 dogs               1
3 light              2
4 paper              2
5 table              3
6 NA                 6
```

So my question is- what is causing the NA row in Subject?  Is it all other records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NA` appears for those values where there are no words in `keep` appearing in that row so there is nothing to extract.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%  mutate(Subject = str_extract(words, keep))

#                   words Subject
#1             paper book   paper
#2             food press    <NA>
#3       computer monitor    <NA>
#4      my fancy speakers    <NA>
#5            my two dogs    dogs
#6          the old couch   couch
#7          the new couch   couch
#8          loud speakers    <NA>
#9           wasted paper   paper
#10   put the dishes away    <NA>
#11         set the table   table
#12   put it on the table   table
#13     lets go to church    <NA>
#14   turn out the lights   light
#15 why are the lights on   light
#16    the table is light   table
```

For example, for 2nd row `'food press'` there are no values from `"dogs|paper|table|light|couch"` in it hence it returns `NA`.

Comment: Great!  Thank you. Is there a way to double count the last row in the data frame your produced since it has both “table” and “light” in it?

Comment: `str_extract` will return only 1 (first) value that it captures from the pattern. If you want to capture all of them use `str_extract_all` but note that `str_extract_all` returns a list.